# QML enabled property and inheritance : disable parent and enable child?

Tags: inheritance, qml, qt5.3

I have a `MyInnerRectangle` component inside a `MyRectangle`.
I want to be able to set `MyInnerRectangle.enabled` to `true` even if `MyRectangle.enabled` is set to `false`.

**Is that possible ? If yes how ?**

I may have misunderstood how `enabled` property works.

I tried this :
Disclaimer, these files may not work properly and I work with Qt 5.3.2 (an old version).

```cpp
// MyInnerRectangle.qml
import QtQuick 2.3
import UI_Components 1.0

Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("InnerRectangle : enabled: " + enabled + ", visible: " + visible)
    }
}
```

```cpp
// MyRectangle.qml
import QtQuick 2.3
import UI_Components 1.0

Rectangle {
    property alias innerEnabled: innerRectangle.enabled

    color: "green"
    anchors.fill: parent

    MyInnerRectangle {
        id: innerRectangle

        visible: enabled

        width: parent.height/2
        height: parent.height/2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

In the main.qml (this file may not be complete, as it is a part of my app)

```cpp
// in main.qml
MyRectangle {
    enabled : false
    innerEnabled: true

    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

But this will display :

```
 qml: InnerRectangle : enabled: false, visible: false
```

When I expect `true`

Comment: The question isn't clear, you probably have to clarify that. Btw, changing `enabled` will change `enabled` for all nested items to the same value. Since  `innerEnabled` is alias it will be changed to false after changing `enabled` to false for the root item. assigning a value in `main.qml` for `innerEnabled` do nothing in this case. Anyway, I highly recommend avoiding such `inner*` logic and building relationships between items in a more understandable and declarative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#enabled-prop) are pretty clear on this:

> Setting this property directly affects the enabled value of child items. When set to false, the enabled values of all child items also become false. When set to true, the enabled values of child items are returned to true, unless they have explicitly been set to false.

So if MyRectangle is disabled, its children must be disabled too. My suggestion if you want to break that link between parent/child is to simply make up a new property that you have complete control over. So instead of setting `enabled`, set `myEnabled` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: I had understood that you also could explicitly set enabled to true. But in fact you are not allowed to do that. I misread the doc.